# Cursor jumps to the top right corner when using Touchpad in combination with the mouse buttons

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, touchpad, cursor

I installed Xubuntu 16.04 on a new Lenovo E460 and following problem arose: When both the left mouse button is pressed and the touchpad is used, the cursor jumps to the top right corner of the screen when you remove your finger from the touchpad. For instance, when you want to mark a longer passage of text and you have to reset your finger to the right because the touchpad is not big enough, the curser jumps and you mark the entire page, scrolling all the way up. This doesn't happen when you remove your finger from the mouse button first, and the trackpoint isn't affected as well. Also, using the trackpoint mouse button instead of the touchpad one also doesn't show the problem. However, on Windows 10 the touchpad works fine.

Messing with the sensitivity settings doesn't help, neither did reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

Thank you in advance if you have any ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to look at the configuration of the synaptics driver by using `synclient -l`. You can change the settings by `synclient <variableName>=<value>`.

Maybe your desktop environment setting does something special by issuing a 'right' or 'middle' click. You can try the `evtest` program (installable by `sudo apt-get install evtest`). It lists all received user input events from a `/dev/input/event*` device on the console until you do a `<ctrl>+c`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although the touchpad doesn't move the cursor when your finger is on the the lower area (which is designated for button presses) it somehow logs something when your finger rests on the left mouse button. This makes it pretty impossible to see the actual button press among the rest. I also forgot to add that the issue doesn't happen when using the mouse buttons of the trackball instead. Maybe the trackpad has problems with multitouch gestures?

Comment: Also, looking at the synclient -l output didn't help, sadly. I don't think any of these setting are relevant to my problem, no "snap to corner" or similar. I can disable drag & drop completely, that's all..